# Displaying big numbers in xtable properly

Tags: r, xtable, displayobject

I know it might seem as a trivial question but I tried really hard to find solution and it was impossible.
Assume I have a data frame like this where one column contatins big numbers:

```
Id    Value
1     2158456456456.78
2     123354554.24
3     72323211215.77
```

I want to put that data frame into latex document using function xtable but I don't want the table to display the numbers like above but in a formatted way like this:

```
Id                   Value
1     2 158 456 456 456.78
2           123 354 554.24
3        72 323 211 215.77
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try

```
options(scipen = 100) # to remove exponential notation
df$val <- prettyNum(df$Value,  big.mark=" ")
  Id         Value               val
1  1 2158456456457 2 158 456 456 457
2  2     123354554       123 354 554
3  3   72323211216    72 323 211 216
```

> 'scipen': A penalty to be applied when deciding to print
>             numeric values in fixed or exponential notation.

Answer (score 3):

You can pass the arguments for `formatC` directly to print.xtable:

```
print(xtable(df1), type = "latex", format.args=list(big.mark = " "))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
format(2158456456457,big.mark=" ",scientific=F)
```